# Type 'Error' does not conform to protocol 'RawRepresentable'

Tags: swift, rawrepresentable

Changing my playground code to Swift 3, Xcode suggested changing

```
enum Error: ErrorType {
    case NotFound
}
```

to

```
enum Error: Error {
    case NotFound
}
```

but now I get the title error and I don't know how to get the enum to conform to that protocol.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is that you've named your error type `Error` – which conflicts with the standard library `Error` protocol (therefore Swift thinks you've got a circular reference).

You could refer to the Swift `Error` protocol as `Swift.Error` in order to disambiguate:

```
enum Error : Swift.Error {
    case NotFound
}
```

But this will mean that any future references to `Error` in your module will refer to *your* `Error` type, not the Swift `Error` protocol (you'll have to disambiguate again).

Therefore the easiest solution by far would be simply renaming your error type to something more descriptive.

Comment: So, in the old version, I would not have been able to name my enum ErrorType, but now that the Swift protocol name has been changed to Error, I can't use Error, right?

Comment: @Shades Yup, that's correct – if you turn "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" to "Yes" in your build settings (which will use Swift 2.3), you can try it for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because you are "overriding" the existing declaration of`Error` which is a `protocol`. So you have to choose another (probably more descriptive) name for your "Error" `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem too, although i declared my enum with specific name.

The reason is that I'm using Realm and it has `Error` class, which makes the confusing between `Swift.Error` and `RealmSwift.Error`.

The solution is specifying `RealmSwift.Error` in the declaration.

```
// before
enum MyError: Error { ... }
// after
enum MyError: Swift.Error { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this block in an AVCapture session and it works in Swift 3 + iOS 10. Using an NSError as a RawValue might address what Hamish was referring to above regarding future references to Error.

```
enum Error : Swift.Error {
    typealias RawValue = NSError

    case failedToAddInput
    case failedToAddOutput
    case failedToSetVideoOrientation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I forgot to put `import Foundation` at the top of my file.  Just sharing in case it helps someone else.